# How to serialize and deserialise mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, serialization, actionmailer

How can I serialise the mailer so that it can be stored for further use?

The serialised data should be disconnected and self sufficient to be delivered on separate machine that should deliver that message (not knowing about database or anything else).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you usually send emails with this:

```
MyMailer.some_email(...).deliver
```

Instead delivering it, you can convert it to a string and transfer the string to another server:

```
raw_mail = MyMailer.some_email(...).to_s
```

On another server, send the email:

```
Mail.new(raw_mail).deliver
```

Comment: This seems to work except that there's no `Mail#send` method. I tried the `Mail#deliver` but I think it doesn't pick the mailer SMTP settings.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. You're right about Mail#deliver. I don't know how are you trying to send the emails from the separate machine. But I think you need to copy SMTP settings to the separate machine.

Comment: The separate machine hosts the same Rails app. So I reckon it should pick it up. But I'm more curious about the `#to_s` method on mailer. Is it documented that it creates full raw email ready to be sent? Also would it handle things like attachments etc?

Comment: Since Mail is separate from ActionMailer, it doesn't share ActionMailer's SMTP settings. By default it tries to connect to localhost:25. See https://github.com/mikel/mail