# Rails 3.2 Serialize & Deserialize Mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to save email to a database, to send it later via a rake task. It was pretty easy in rails 2.3.8 (TMail), but I'm having trouble with rails 3.2.

Once I get the Mail object (mail), I call mail.encoded to serialize the email. I save this to the database.

My rake task loads the encoded message, but I can't find a way to recreate the mail object and call deliver (deserialize).

Mail.new(mail.encoded) seems like it should work, but the delivery fails because Mail.new doesn't get the default ActionMailer SMTP settings.

Anyone else doing something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264424/how-to-serialize-and-deserialise-mailers, but they still have the Mail.new issue of not picking up SMTP settings.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, got this working.

To serialize the email I do the following.

```
email = mail(:to => 'to@me.com',  ....)
string = mail.encoded

# later one

mail.new(email.string)
Mail.deliver(mail)
```

This appears to skip any HTML validation.

I can't set the Mail send settings (SMTP, etc), but I think it defaults to :sendmail, and that's working on the web server.

Comment: To make smtp settings work add `ActionMailer::Base.wrap_delivery_behavior(mail)` before delivering mail